# What is 'expendable' in logic and how to explain 'tautology' given this image?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, symbolic-logic, propositional-logic

This image is from http://www.nfillion.com/index.php/teaching/9-logic-112. According to this, a proposition can have 4 basic properties: (1) necessarily, (2) not possibly, (3) missing, and (4) expendable. What does it mean by 'expendable'?

So, according to the following image, a proposition is 'not contingent' when it is 'necessarily' and 'not possibly' true. This does make sense to me. However, for a proposition that is a 'tautology' how to explain it in the same manner? Why does 'tautology' have a property of being 'not possibly' true?

[image: Logical term]

Comment: You have to search for defintions...

Comment: It seems a "combinatorial" schema. We have some combinations quite intuitive: it seems that we have to read "contingent" as the combination of "possible" and "not necessary". This sound fine. Thus "not contingent" must be: "either not possible or necessary" and also this is consistent with the image.

Comment: If this approach is correct, then "missing" is either contradictory or not actual: Ok ? An "expendable" (???) is either contradictory or actual: ??? IMO these are not usual concepts.

Comment: Tautology is... [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)): a formula that is true in every interpretation

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am familiar with almost all of these terms except expendable and missing. I guess those extra unusual terms are introduced to make the schema symmetric, all these terms do not have the same/similar level of importance.

Comment: Have you found in Fillon's web site some Lecture Notes related to modal logic?

Comment: It seems that the edges can not be interpreted in a consistent way: By the usual definition, a proposition is contingent iff it is unnecessary *and* possible, and it is not contingent iff it is impossible *or* necessary. For the first notion, edges coming in from the outside must be read as conjoined, but for the second notion, they must be read as disjoined. So I don't see how one could deduce the definitions fo these terms form the graph alone, you probably have to look them up.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, I have not. I tried to search for lecture notes for this course but seems like they are not available online. Anyway, someone should close this question, I guess. I thought these are important parts of modal logic but it turns out it is not the case. Most of the standard texts don't even have these terms.